# An attempt at making a neat ls

Tags: bash

This is a simple script to make ls output first folders, then files, then other stuff (symlink). I think this is really neat and would like to share the script in exchange for comments.

It should be noted that I'm working with *GNU findutils* and *coreutils*.

**Some basic criteria that I'm aiming for include:**

- lssort must accept the same arguments as ls
- lssort should depend on `bash`, `find`, `ls` and `xargs`
- the output must not be prefixed with "./"

  **Problems:**

  - arguments can not be augmented (-CFXtrs does not work)

  **Script**

```
   
#! /bin/bash
#source $HOME/.scripts/string_manipulation.mergeme
function trim {
    local var="$@"
    #$ var="  hello space    "
    #$ echo ">"
    #$ >
    var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}" # rm leading whitespace characters
    var="${var%"${var##*[![:space:]]}"}" # rm trailing whitespace characters
    echo -n "$var"
}

function arrayContains {
    # remove the shortest needle from array and compare lengths
    # needs more testing...
    declare -a array
    declare -a arrayLess
    declare needle
    array=( "${!1}" ); shift        # expand the passed array name
    needle="$@"                     # try to match the rest as a string
    arrayLess=( `trim "${array[@]#${needle}}"` )    # remove value $needle
    if [ ${#array[@]} -eq 0 ];then                  return 1 ;fi
    if [ ${#array[@]} -eq ${#arrayLess[@]} ];then   return 1 ;fi
    if [ ${#array[@]} -lt ${#arrayLess[@]} ];then   return 1 ;fi
    return 0
}

# d dir f file p named pipe (FIFO) l sylink s socket D door (Solaris) 
# c character (unbuffered) special b block (buffered) special

function finddirs {
    find "$@" \
        -maxdepth 1 -depth -type d \
        -regextype gnu-awk -regex "$REGEX" \
        -printf '%f\0'
}
function findfiles {
    find "$@" \
        -maxdepth 1 -depth -type f \
        -regextype gnu-awk -regex "$REGEX" \
        -printf "%f\0"
}
function findspecials {
    find "$@" \
        -maxdepth 1 -depth \( -type l   -o -type p   -o -type s \) \
        -regextype gnu-awk -regex "$REGEX" \
        -printf "%f\0"
}
##
## vars and such
##
validswitches=(-X -l -r -t -C -F -1 -a -A -d -s)
PATHS=()
FPATHS=""
LSSWITCHES=""
ORIGIN_DIR="`pwd`"
LSHIDDEN="^\./.+"       # gnu-awk regex for find, single dot does not match
LSNORMAL="^\./[^\.]+.+" # exclude files starting with .
LS=ls\ --color=auto

ARG=$1
ARGC=0
while [ "$ARG" != "" ];
do
    if [ `arrayContains validswitches[@] $ARG ;echo $?` -eq 0 ];then
        LSSWITCHES="${LSSWITCHES} $ARG"
        unset ARG
    fi

    if [ -d "$ARG" ];then
        #PATHS="${PATHS} $ARG"
        PATHS[${ARGC}]=$ARG
        let ARGC=ARGC+1
    else
        FPATHS="${FPATHS} $ARG"
    fi
    shift
    ARG=$1
done

# FIX only -A excludes . and .. 
if [[ "$LSSWITCHES" =~ '-a' || "$LSSWITCHES" =~ '-A' ]]; then
    REGEX=$LSHIDDEN
else
    REGEX=$LSNORMAL
fi

#PATHS=`trim $PATHS`
FPATHS=`trim $FPATHS`

if [ ${#FPATHS} -eq 0 ]; then 
    if [ ${#PATHS[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        PATHS=(".")
    fi
fi
for arg in "${PATHS[@]}";
do
    if [[ ${#arg} -eq 1 && "$arg" == "/" ]];then 
        p=/
    else
        #p=${arg%%/}
        p=$arg
    fi

    cd "$p"
    if [[ "$p" != "." && "$p" != "./" ]];then echo "$p": ;fi
    finddirs | xargs -r0 $LS $LSSWITCHES -d 
    findfiles | xargs -r0 $LS $LSSWITCHES 
    findspecials | xargs -r0 $LS $LSSWITCHES -d
    [ ${#PATHS[@]} -gt 1 ] && echo 
    cd $ORIGIN_DIR
done

echo $FPATHS |xargs -r $LS $LSSWITCHES 
#echo paths.:\ size: ${#PATHS[@]}
#echo fpaths:\
```

- [lssort](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~rakhmato/bash/lssort)

[image: lssort.png]

Comment: Alright, done. Good points.

Comment: The coreutils people have made this easier:  `ls --group-directories-first`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use `getopt` or `getopts` to parse the options, you can use multiple options together, and it would simplify your code quite a bit. [Example](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/e48ba0c2c892ac2426a1e6b6e5f9930253398b70/scripts/make-links.sh#L67).
2. When you create arrays explicitly (`name=(values)`) you don't need to `declare` it first.
3. `arrayContains` should take one `needle` and then the contents of the array in question. This is how it works in other languages, and is easier to program and more explicit than using an array reference and concatenated needles. Also, when expanding `needle` the values will be concatenated with a space between them, which is rather arbitrary.
4. If `needle` is empty, `arrayContains` should `return 0` regardless of the array contents.
5. You can merge the `if` statements in `arrayContains` by separating them with `-o`:

   ```
   if [ $a -eq 0 -o $b -eq 0 -o $c -eq $a ]
   ```
6. <strike>`ls` works with [globs rather than regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) by default.</strike> The `find*` functions will not return the same filenames as `ls` with the same input. For example, run `touch example && mkdir eclectic` and compare

   ```
   ls [e]*
   ```

   with

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -depth -type f -regextype gnu-awk -regex "[e]*"
   ```
7. You should be able to get the current working directory with `$PWD` rather than `pwd` to save a fork. This makes the code a tiny bit faster, without losing clarity, and fixes a very common but little known bug: The `` `command` `` construct (identical to the preferred [`$(command)` when using Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)) *removes newlines from the end of the command output*. That means if you `mkdir $'foo\n' && cd $'foo\n'` , `` ORIGIN_DIR="`pwd`" `` will give the wrong result, but `ORIGIN_DIR="$PWD"` will give the right one.
8. [Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting), for example do `ARG="$1"` to enable working with whitespace in filenames. This is a [very tricky subject](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).
9. If you want to get this working with [all filenames](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh), you'll need to use an array to store the `find` results before sending them to `ls`

Comment: Wow, tanks a lot! I've been avoiding getopts for far too long. I'll read up on it. Would you care to elaborate on why point 7 is relevant?

Comment: I meant point 6 about ls working on shell globs rather than regex. What would I gain by running ls with regex?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I have those confused, but thank you anyway.

Comment: As far as I know, point 7 is not correct - command substitution strips _a newline_ from the end of the commands output, not _all newlines_.  And pwd prints a newline after its output.  So, pwd would emit "foo\n\n", command substitution would strip the last newline, and you'd be left with "foo\n" - which is the correct directory name.

Comment: @godlygeek Wrong: `printf '%q' "$(printf '%s\n\n' 'foo')"` prints `foo` and no newlines.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected - I clearly screwed something up when I tested that a minute ago.  Nevermind me.